# Setting up personal notebook for BYOD

Tags: windows-10, security, user-profiles

Like most of the employee, I have a company issued notebook which can let me do most of the normal work (e.g. send/receive email, browse the web...).

However, much of my responsibility is involving development work, such that I'll need to install various software (e.g. JDK, nodejs, docker...) from time to time. Since I have no administrator right and those software I need is usually not in the approved list, if I need to follow the proper procedure, it will take at least two to three months to install a software as simple as the python run-time. While I can install some software (e.g. Visual Studio Code, Git...) without administrator privilege, many tools and configuration I need cannot be used since I'm just a normal user. Even if the software is installed, their version will always be at least six month behind the latest technology in the market.

I understand in a security standpoint, the company cannot grant everyone admin right and will need to test the software thoroughly before letting them in the corporate network, but this bureaucracy has made me impossible to do my work. Getting the admin password from colleague is impractical in long term, and there's nothing in my boss's power to make my situation better. So like what most of my colleague do, I intend to bring my own personal laptop for work.

I have a notebook computer with Windows 10 Pro installed, and in order to separate my personal and work files/software/settings in my laptop, I've come up with a few options:

1. Install a fresh copy of Windows alongside with the original installation. This is the cleanest solution I can think of, but this involve a lot of work and I'll need to purchase new license for everything.
2. Create a virtual machine (VM) and do everything in this VM. This is similar to the first option but there's significant performance penalty, and the license problem is still there.
3. Create a new user account and do every work thing in that. This is a simpler solution, but registry and some system config will need to be shared among personal and work environment.
4. Just use the existing configuration of my personal laptop and do my work there.

For some work requirement I'll need to have some specific network configuration and install some plugin in my laptop. For option 3 and 4, how can I separate personal and work files/software/settings effectively?

Comment: Corporate environment questions are off-topic here as we can't give the right answer. You really need to solve it with your boss and IT. There could be different scenarios including you get another work laptop with the same security measures as all company laptops but disconnected from company network and you get admin privileges on it. Or other extreme could be nobody in the company makes development and your company just outsources it.

Comment: I believe there is a misunderstanding, mentioning about the corporate environment is just to provide some background information, the situation is that I have only left with one option - which is BYOD, and this question is just asking about how to configure my personal laptop for this use case that I can best separate the personal and work configuration in my laptop.

Comment: "Create a virtual machine (VM) and do everything in this VM. This is similar to the first option but there's significant performance penalty,".  Significant? LIke 1% less?

Answer (score 4):

Don't solve a social problem with a technical solution.

If you work "covertly" to take over your PC, then authorities (IT Dept, your own manager, perhaps others) will have cause for alarm.

Instead, write polite requests explaining why it's impossible to work without it.  Keep a copy if you do it on paper.  BCC yourself if you do it on email.  It's an important document for when you quit or are fired for nonperformance.

And yes, getting fired for nonperformance when a bureaucrat is in your way is a real thing.  Especially in larger companies with inflexible rules.

For better or worse, now you know that companies can do this to you.  Ask questions in future interviews like "Do I get local admin priviledges by default?"

Comment: "getting fired for nonperformance when a bureaucrat is in your way is a real thing. " - For a large part of the world, this would be a perfectly valid reason, to let an employee go.  So while I don't disagree you should keep records, doing so is not a guarantee, you will be able to keep your job.  **There are tons of people that are productive in the situation the author describes.**